# using bootstrap-datepicker-rails, now my dates are strings, but I need to save to db as dates

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, date, bootstrap-datepicker

After much stress, finally got the datepicker gem to succesfully open a mini-calendar and enter the date in the field. 
Despite using this jQuery script,

```
$jQuery ->

$(document).on "focus", "[data-provide~='datepicker']", (e) ->
 - $(this).datepicker
 - format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
 - weekStart: 1
 - autoclose: true;
```

...the date returned in the field is still in mm/dd/yyyy format.  That's fine as long as I want to use a string field in the database (and I may wind up reconstructing the db that way) but I need to do some simple math functions on start_date - end_date, which is why I created the database with date fields instead of string fields in the first place.

So I need to do one of two things--either reformat my db date fields to strings (and use Date.parse() in my math calculations) or find a way to save the date returned to the text field, generated by this:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :end_date, 'data-provide' => 'datepicker' %>
  </div>
```

...as a mysql date field, formatted yyyy-mm-dd.  Is there a way to do this in the _form.html.erb document prior to submitting the form?

Or, alternatively, is there a parameter/option in the bootstrap-datepicker-rails plugin that will allow the input field to be a date field instead of a text_field, or to convert the return value to a date instead of a string?

Comment: On a hunch I used `f.date_field` instead of `f.text_field`, and voila, 2 calendar widgets appeared (one generated by bootstrap-datepicker, I assume). The bootstrap widget didn't save the date, but the "new" one did. Does rails include this for free using `date_field`, or is the gem still generating it? (I erased the javascript commands but not the datepicker.js or .css). If so, why are people struggling with datepicker plugins? New in rails 4, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

// here solution
     object.date = Date.strptime(params[:date], '%m/%d/%Y').to_date

// change date format according your code