# Rails 5 and Datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using this gem : [rails datepicker](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails)

I have this field in my form :

```
<%= f.text_field :date_mes, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Date MES', :data => {:provide => 'datepicker'} %>
```

It saves this data like a String object, is it possible to save it as a Date object in my database ?

My create function in controller :

```
def create
  @analyse = AnalyseHuile.new (allowed_params)
  if @analyse.save
    redirect_to huile_path, success: 'Success'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

and allowed_params :

```
def allowed_params
  params.require(:analyse_huile).permit(:date_mes)
end
```

Comment: Looks like your database column date_mes is a char type. Show your actual `db/schema.rb`

Comment: @Зелёный, it is `t.date "date_mes"`

Comment: Show all related params and your controller code.

Comment: I updated, I checked my db, and it saves a 'nil' value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will save the date object in the database.
In this case date_mes should have the datatype date or datetime.

Comment: Yeah, in my schema.db I defined :date_mes as a Date object. But my field saves it like a String because I have to use a "text_field" to get datepicker to work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005758/using-bootstrap-datepicker-rails-now-my-dates-are-strings-but-i-need-to-save-t
Please look at this link, this might be helpful.